# Vue JS routing user role, lost user and data when reloaded

Tags: vue.js, user-roles

I made the user role with vue js, but there were bugs in it when I reloaded the dashboard after logging in and the user role was lost and the data inside was also lost

Answer (score 1):

set and get data from the local storage in vue life-cycle-hooks to solve this issue.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp